# Redirecting a url to a local file using the webRequest api for chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm having trouble using the webRequest api for chrome extensions to redirect a url

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
return {
  redirectUrl : "file:///C:/hello.html"
};
}, {
urls : ["<all_urls>"]
}, ["blocking"]);
```

I can redirect to any http or https address but not a file location anyone know why...?

Answer (score 8):

```
redirectUrl : chrome.extension.getURL("hello.html")
```

I successed like above, hello.html is in extension folder.

Comment: Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

Answer (score 6):

1. First, you must put your file inside the extension folder (or inside a subfolder of the extension folder).
2. Then, you must declare it as a `"web_accessible_resources"` in the manifest file.

**Example:**
If your extension folder is MyExt, and the file you want to use is `"MyExt/path/to/file.html"`. Then you should add this to the manifest file:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
   "path/to/file.html"
]
```

In general, any file that will be used outside the extension should be declared in the `"web_accessible_resources"` array.

**Note** that the declaration is just the relative path of the file inside the extension folder.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Extension can not access local resources\files in any manner it is functionality put for security, Having said that can i know what is specific reason for redirecting to Local URL(Being Extension web spread)

Comment: As a feature so someone could redirect a web request to a javascript file that was on their local computer. If this is the case then will just have to accept it can't be done. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

To redirect to a local file, I have done a trick.
This is my code:

1. file: background.js

   ```
   chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
     return {
       redirectUrl : chrome.extension.getURL("index.html")
     };
   }, {
   urls : ["<all_urls>"]
   }, ["blocking"]);
   function r(tabId) {
   chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {
       "url": redirectUrl
   });
   ```

   }

   chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {

   ```
   if (request.redirect) {
           chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(w){
               chrome.tabs.query({windowId : w.id}, function(t){
                   r(t.id);
               });
           });
   }
   sendResponse({
       redirected: redirectUrl
   });
   ```

   });
2. Create file index.html in your extension with content:

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
       <title>Redirecting...</title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="redirect.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body >
   </body>
   ```
3. create file redirect.js:

   function request(){
       chrome.extension.sendRequest({  redirect: true  }, function(rsp){ });
       }

   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
       request();
       return false;
   });

Comment: Javascript pages redirected this way do not have access to the page's `window`.